# How to add an Image to an Android TextView via XML

Tags: java, android, image, android-layout, textview

I'm trying to add an image to an Android TextView, but nothing shows. This is how I'm going about it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="RevUpload">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_airplay_black_24dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">44dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

This is how I call it:

```
TextView about = new TextView(mContext);
about.setText("About");
about.setTextAppearance(R.style.RevUpload);
```

What is it that I'm missing? Is my approach wrong?

I do know that I can add it via a drawable as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="RevUpload">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_airplay_black_24dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">44dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I would, however like to add it via a style XML file.

Vielen dank im voraus.

Comment: check my ans and ask me in case of any query

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `android:src` only shows an image for `ImageView`. If you want to add a drawable to a `TextView` in Java code, use one of `TextView`'s `setCompoundDrawables()` methods.

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp, 0);
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello world"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

### Screenshot of emulator

[image]

### Further reading

[TextView.setCompoundDrawables() documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How can I resize it via your approach @BenP?

Answer (score 1):

try this it will help you

**Read your drawable**

```
Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_img);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) dr).getBitmap();

// set size of your drable
Drawable img = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, true));
```

**Set your new, scaled drawable "d"**

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, img, 0);
```